# Why does wcalc output rounding symbol (~=) for integer operations (subtraction)?

Tags: calculator

I have noted, that `man wcalc` says:

```
       --ints
           Toggles whether long integers will be abbreviated or not.  This  conflicts  with  engineering
           notation for large numbers, but not for decimals.

...

Rounding in the command-line version is denoted by a  tilde  before  the  equals  sign  (~=).
```

So, I try this:

```
$ wcalc --version
wcalc 2.5

$ wcalc 1588890124670286510-1588890124626020545
~= 4.4266e+07
```

Ok, so shown in scientific notation, as expected; then I try:

```
$ wcalc --ints 1588890124670286510-1588890124626020545
~= 44265965
```

So, it shows as full integer - again, as expected - but for some reason, it says `~=`, meaning the result is "rounded".

This kind of confuses me, because shouldn't integer operations (subtraction, at least), be exact?

Why is the rounding symbol there, then - what is it implying?

Comment: Maybe the answer is under `--round`? `In some cases, Wcalc may think  that  the  number  has
           been rounded even if it shouldn't have been necessary (this is because of
           the way floating point numbers are represented internally).`

Comment: Ah, thanks for that @schrodigerscatcuriosity  - I missed that part; much appreciated!